# How to make one-line choices generator from nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, django

I have such structure:

```
actions = {
    'cat1': {
        'visit': {
            'id': 1,
            'description': 'Desc 1',
            'action': 'Act 1',
        },
    },
    'cat2': {
        'download': {
            'id': 2,
            'description': 'Desc 2',
            'action': 'Act 2',
        },
        'click': {
            'id': 3,
            'description': 'Desc 3',
            'action': 'Act 3',
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

And following code for generating tuple of tuples for django choice field:

```
CHOICES = []
for a in actions.values():
    for c in a.values():
        CHOICES.append((c['id'], c['description']))
```

Is it possible to write above code in one line nested for loop?

Comment: It's *possible*, not sure it's any clearer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CHOICES = [(c['id'], c['description']) for a in actions.values() for c in a.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

With map and reduce:

```
 map(lambda x : [x['id'],x['description']],reduce(lambda x,y:x+y.values(),actions.values(),[]))
```